# Pandas sort column value without sorting datetime accordingly

Tags: pandas, sorting

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({})
df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(np.arange(0,3), unit='h', origin='2018-08-01 03:00:00')
df['X'] = [3,5,4]
df['Y'] = [6,7,8]

                 Date  X  Y
0 2018-08-01 03:00:00  3  6
1 2018-08-01 04:00:00  5  7
2 2018-08-01 05:00:00  4  8
```

I want to sort the values of the column X from largest to smallest, without moving the order of the Date. I don't want to index my date and preferably I dont want to make copies of the dataframe which I merge after X is sorted. The result should look like:

```
                 Date  X  Y
0 2018-08-01 03:00:00  5  7
1 2018-08-01 04:00:00  4  8
2 2018-08-01 05:00:00  3  6
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({})
df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(np.arange(0,6), unit='h', origin='2018-08-03:00:00')
df['X'] = [3,5,4,1,8,2]
df['Y'] = [6,7,8,6,7,8]
df['name'] = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
```

I want to sort as above, but now I want to groupby column level 'name'. The result should look like:

```
                 Date  X  Y name 
1 2018-08-01 04:00:00  5  7 1
2 2018-08-01 05:00:00  4  8 1
0 2018-08-01 03:00:00  3  6 1
4 2018-08-01 07:00:00  8  7 2
5 2018-08-01 08:00:00  2  8 2
3 2018-08-01 06:00:00  1  6 2
```

So for the first name=1, all X-values are sorted from high to low, and then for name=2 all X-values are sorted from high to low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is reaasign column `Date` after sorting with removed `inplce=True` parameter:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['X'], ascending=False).assign(Date = df['Date'].to_numpy())
print (df)

                 Date  X  Y
1 2018-08-01 03:00:00  5  7
2 2018-08-01 04:00:00  4  8
0 2018-08-01 05:00:00  3  6
```

Or you can reassign sorted columns converted to numpy array:

```
df[['X','Y']] = df.sort_values(by=['X'], ascending=False)[['X','Y']].to_numpy()
```

EDIT Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by both columns instead only one:

```
df1 = (df.sort_values(['name','X'], ascending=[True, False])
         .assign(Date = df['Date'].to_numpy()))
print (df1)
                 Date  X  Y  name
1 2018-08-01 03:00:00  5  7     1
2 2018-08-01 04:00:00  4  8     1
0 2018-08-01 05:00:00  3  6     1
4 2018-08-01 06:00:00  8  7     2
5 2018-08-01 07:00:00  2  8     2
3 2018-08-01 08:00:00  1  6     2
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by:

```
df = df.groupby(['name'],group_keys=False).apply(lambda _df: _df.sort_values(by=['X'], ascending=True)).assign(Date = df['Date'].to_numpy())
```

Comment: still interesting about solution?

Comment: No, I am not interested anymore. I got the solution I wanted. Thanks for the help

Comment: I know there was some comment, but I was offline, so forget for get response

Comment: Your answer should be `df1 = df.groupby(['name'],group_keys=False).apply(lambda _df: _df.sort_values(by=['X'], ascending=False)).assign(Date = df['Date'].to_numpy())`, my answer was edited.